# How to find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I am trying to solve a puzzle and the 
Problem statement is: Find the largest palindrome made from the product of two 3-digit numbers.

I'm new to this so please help!

Comment: there are plenty of online language converters out there.  Use one.

Comment: Any links sir? Sorry for that i'm new to programming

Comment: Are you new to Google/Bing/Yahoo too?

Comment: What I mean is do you know which is the best and easy to use one?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a basic outline that should get you going:

```
Dim max As Integer = 999 * 999
Dim min As Integer = 100 * 100
Dim result As Integer

While max > min AndAlso Not (IsPalindrome(max) AndAlso Not IsPrime(max)) Then
    max -= 1   
End While
result = max
```

And then the functions you need:

```
Public Function IsPalindrome(ByVal value As Integer) As Boolean
   Dim str1 As String = value.ToString()
   Dim chars() As Char = str1.ToCharArray()
   Array.Reverse(chars)
   Dim str2 As New String(chars)
   Return (str1 = str2)
End Function

Public Function IsPrime(ByVal value As Integer) As Boolean
    If value Mod 2 = 0 Then
        Return False
    End If
    For i = 3 To value / 2 + 1 Step 2
        If value Mod i = 0 Then
            Return False
        End If
    Next
    Return True
End Function
```

Comment: So what do you think the number that is being multiplied to get the product of `997799` sir?

Comment: You didn't ask for that.

Answer (score 0):

Here is C/C++ code for solving this problem, you'll need to do 2 things- 1) convert this into VB code and 2) implement the isPalindrome() function.

```
int highestPalindrome = 12321; // 111 * 111
for( int i = 111; i <= 999; i++) {
    for( int j = 111; j<= 999; j++) {
        int value = i*j;
        if( isPalindrome(value) )
            if( value > highestPalindrome )
                highestPalindrome = value;
    }
}
```

There are NUMEROUS solutions you can find on Stack Overflow for writing the isPalindrome() function.

Comment: He wants the biggest, so maybe he should start at 999 * 999 and work down, rather than 111 * 111 and working up. Then he can quit after the first match.

Comment: I had thought about that, but 999 * 999 is not a palindrome :)  The result is 998,001

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn I guess not, even if he starts with the biggest value, he can't be sure it the largest palindrome until he iterates over the entire 3 digit space. This is because he will encounter 999*111 earlier than 998*997 (these are not palindromes, just random numbers so that you get my point :))